# Should I start using HTML5 and CSS3 and avoid using previous versions?

Tags: html, css

I need to know if I have to use only latest versions of HTML and CSS and absolutely avoid previous elements to create websites?

Comment: It purely depends on what you prefer. HTML5 and CSS3 do have more features than earlier versions, but earlier versions also work well.

Comment: What will you do when the company you work provides Lamborghini to travel to your work place instead of you coming by some cheap model car?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you learn older versions of html and css you will be fine going to html5 and css3 later but I recommend starting with html5 and css3 because many features of older versions of html don't work in html5 so there is no point to learn then just to find that they won't work in the new version and have to learn the new way. But be warned some browsers don't support html5.

Comment: Thank you for the informative response, I will start with latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML5 ands CSS3, just know that some CSS3 features dont work in certain browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the good response.